# Tubular use more than 1 video

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, tubular

I am using [Tubular](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/) a JS plugin that shows Youtube videos in the background. Currently the function only allows for one video so you can't loop through an array of videos. This is what I want to achieve.

The function works like this

```
$('#wrapper').tubular({videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8'});
```

I want to extend it to include multiple video IDs that will play one after another, something like this.

```
$('#wrapper').tubular({videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8', 'uPZ8LZQMPys', 'zY49-LHyBk0'});
```

Any ideas will be appreciated :)